# How can I set the transaction isolation level of a Mojo::Pg::Transaction?

Tags: postgresql, perl, mojolicious

I'm writing a small application using Mojolicious, and I would like to implement some sort of optimistic locking for updates of a table.

I want to set ["Repeatable Read"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ) transaction isolation level to the transaction I have, so that any concurrent updates fail (rollback) and only the first one goes through.

How can I set this on a `Mojo::Pg::Transaction` object? The documentation on that part seems a bit sparse (https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Pg/Transaction), focusing mainly on creating and committing a transaction.

Comment: `$tx->db->dbh->do("SET TRANSACTION REPEATABLE READ");`